# Modify Navigation bar in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, suitebar

I want to hide the Newsfeed and Sites links in the navigation bar, and add another link. How can this be done?

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and can use SharePoint Designer 2013

Answer (score 0):

**Using SharePoint Designer**

1. Open Site in the SharePoint designer
2. Open the seattle master page and delete the following text

   SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ID_SuiteLinksDelegate/>

*Make sure you have copy of the seattle master page before performing this action*

**Using CSS**

For NewsFeed:

```
#suiteLinksBox .ms-core-suiteLink-a[id$='ShellNewsfeed'] {
    display: none;
}
```

For Sites:

```
#suiteLinksBox .ms-core-suiteLink-a[id$='ShellSites'] {
    display: none;
}
```

**

**Adding new link**

Locate the text: `id="DeltaSuiteLinks"` and add the below code just below the `DeltaSuiteLinks` tag to add link to suite bar of SharePoint 2013

```
<span id="CustomerSupport" class="ms-core-suiteLink">
    <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" href="<a class="vglnk" href="http://support.crescent.com" rel="nofollow"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>support</span><span>.</span><span>crescent</span><span>.</span><span>com</span></a>">
      <asp:Label ID="lblCS" runat="server" Text="Customer Support"></asp:Label>
    </a>
</span>
```

References:

1. http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-add-links-to-the-top-link-bar-in-sharepoint-sharepoint-2010
2. https://thomasdaly.net/2016/03/05/hide-newsfeed-onedrive-andor-sites-from-the-suite-bar-ribbon-area-for-sharepoint-2013/
3. http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/how-to-add-link-to-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar.html